# Hosting asp net service on IIS - configuration issues

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I have to host an asp net web service on IIS.
Steps I took are well known ( or maybe I missed something ? )

> 1. Copied service folder to C:/inetpub/wwwroot
> 2. Opened IIS, added web site, named Serenity, provided physical path to the 
>      service ( *C:/inetpub/wwwroot/SerenityWS* )
> 3. Application pool set to ASP.NET V4.0

Running it in browser gives:

[image]

Supposingly this service hosted successfully in the past, and now I wonder what went wrong with my .conf file.

[image]

Directory browsing positioned me to the same error line 14.

[image]

---

Here is the problematic portion of web.conf xml...

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/></sectionGroup></sectionGroup></sectionGroup></configSections>
```

---

After removing all offending lines as suggested, I ended up with this, I did not downgrade to CLR 2.0, should it be the solution for this as well ?

[image]

Comment: which version of .NET framework is your Application pool running on? It looks like you are trying to read few .NET 3.5 instructions while running on a newer version of the framework.

Comment: Currently, it is running on .NET 4.0

Comment: ok then you need to remove all the offending lines from your conf. file, they no longer need to be explicited since 4.0.

Comment: It is clearly stated in your exception dump that you have defined a section twice in your config. Remove the red lines from your configuration file and that should solve your issue.

Comment: Switch to CLR 2.0 would be a workaround. If you do want to use CLR 4.0, you need to upgrade the web app, and Microsoft has official articles to guide you.

Comment: Luca, Lex, after removing offending lines I ended up with an error above.
Do you have any suggestions ?